# CAS: How to get the username through the RESTful API

Tags: rest, cas

Can I get the username through the RESTful API at my desktop-application somehow? I don't need to authenticate anymore but I need to know the owner of the TGT when I already have it.

If there is no standard way of solving this, what part do I need to change in my CAS-Server to archive that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a CAS service, request a service ticket for it (POST /cas/v1/tickets/theTGT) and validate it via the CAS service (GET /cas/serviceValidate?service=xxx&ticket=yyyy) to retrieve the CAS username.

Comment: The answer of the validation that is send by the CAS server contains the username? How or where exactly?

Comment: The validation of the service ticket is an XML payload: https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/protocol/CAS-Protocol-Specification.html#head2.5